# Can i use google cloud print using a google service account?

Tags: python, google-cloud-print

I cant use OAuth2 authentication for accessing Google cloud print as I can't have a browser redirection for account selection. So I am trying out Google service account for accessing Google cloud print (suggested method for these scenarios). But under the `googleapiclient.discovery` , I am unable to find a key word for cloud printing. This is the code snippet which I tried.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'secret.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

sqladmin = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta3', credentials=credentials)
```

I am confused at 2 places in the above code snippet.
1. If the scope provided is valid
2. What is the alternative for argument `sqladmin` in `googleapiclient.discovery.build()` function for Google cloud print.